# How to disable some dropdown options in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, drop-down-menu

I Have a Dropdown and that Dropdown have some list of items, Here I need to disable some dropdown options, Disable options means the dropdown options should become disable i.e. not clickable.

I tried like this, But it will only disable 1st and 3rd options, So in further options may change, So below code dosen't work.....

```
 `  ` options={data}
    getOptionDisabled={(option) => {
      // Mention options which needs to be disable
      return option === data[1] || option === data[3]
    }``
```

So Can we get a list of Items and can we Disable those list of Items??? Is that will work???

I am requesting anyone having any Idea to disable some dropdown options.`

Here is my Code:

```
`import React from 'react'
 import { inputs } from '../Common/Data';


`const Dropdown = () => {
    const data = inputs;
    //console.log(data.purpose);
    return (
        <>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <div className="col-4">
                    <select className="form-select" aria-label="Disabled select example">
                        <option selected>Select an Option</option>
                        {data.purpose.map((items) => (
                            //console.log(items.value);
                            <option >{items.value}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </>
    )
}`

export default Dropdown
```

Comment: Have you use any react libraries?

Comment: @sedhal , Thankyou for your reply and No I haven't used any react library, Its Just bootstrap with React.... Can you please Suggest me like how can i do that

Comment: Can you please let me know condition for disable dropdown option

Comment: @sedhal I have a list of countries and in that list all the Countries will be displayed and I am iterating those list with the map and Displaying, Now I need to disable embargoed countries from that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'


const App = () => {
    // let's suppose that is data coming from the backend
    let data = {
        purpose: [
            {
                value: "1",
            },
            {
                value: "2",
            },
            {
                value: "3",
            },
            {
                value: "4",
            },
        ]
    }

    // and if you want to disable 2 and 3 items then you have to restructured the array

    const disabledItemsArr = ["2", "3"]

    // restructured array and here you are adding a new disabled property in the array that will be true or false
    const newArr = data.purpose.map(item => ({...item, disabled: disabledItemsArr.includes(item.value) ? true : false}))

    return (
        <>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <div className="col-4">
                    <select className="form-select" aria-label="Disabled select example">
                        <option selected>Select an Option</option>
                        {newArr.map((items) => (
                            // In the option you can use the disabled property for disable the option
                            <option disabled={items.disabled}>{items.value}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </>
    )
}


export default App;
```

updated code:

```
const disabledItemsArr = ["Credit Card Payment", "Family Support (Workers uninons)"] 
const newArr = data.purpose.map(item => ({...item, disabled: disabledItemsArr.includes(item.value) ? true : false})) 

{newArr.map((items) => (
    // In the option you can use the disabled property for disable the option
    <>
        <option selected>Select an Option</option>
        <option disabled={items.disabled}>{items.value}</option>
    </>
))}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lucy-753vqk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function,
when I use this line restructured array 
    data = data.map(item => ({...data, disabled: disabledItemsArr.includes(item.value) ? true : false}))

Comment: data.purpose.map(item => ({...data, disabled: disabledItemsArr.includes(item.value) ? true : false})) use this

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have also updated the answer.

Comment: Now I am getting this error  : Dropdown.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
for this line : data.purpose.map(item => ({...data, disabled: disabledItemsArr.includes(item.value) ? true : false}))

Comment: I have updated my answer please try again

Comment: Still it saying  Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
My code is like this     const disabledItemsArr = ["Credit Card Payment", "Family Support (Workers uninons)"]........

    data = data.purpose.map(item => ({...data, disabled: disabledItemsArr.includes(item.value) ? true : false}))

<option selected>Select an Option</option>
                        {data?.purpose.map((items) => (
                            //console.log(items.value);
                            <option disabled={items.disabled}>{items.value}</option>
                        ))}

Comment: I updated your code and also I update my answer

Comment: The dropdown list items all are  disabled and show empty when I click on dropdown menu.... Can you try this in Stackbiltz ??

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lucy-753vqk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: There is a minor mistake in update code section in my answer that's why you are getting empty, please try this also

Comment: Yes, Its working .... Thanks a lot .... The only thing to change is {...data } to {...item}  in my updated code

Answer (score 1):

You can change your array accordingly to disable filed value.

```
let { ButtonToolbar, Button, FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl } = ReactBootstrap;

class SelectComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { color: ''};
  }
  
  onPickColor(e){
    console.log('[onPickColor]', this.inputEl )
    this.setState({ color: this.inputEl.value });
  }
  render(){
let data = [{"value" :"India", "disabled" : false}, {"value" :"USA", "disabled" : true}, {"value" :"UK", "disabled" : true}]
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color }}>
        <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
          <ControlLabel>Select</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl 
              onChange={this.onPickColor.bind(this)}
              inputRef={ el => this.inputEl=el }
              componentClass="select" placeholder="select">
            {data.map((items) => (
                 <option disabled={items.disabled}>{items.value}</option> ))}
          </FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <SelectComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Can you please Edit your ans with ReactHooks, I am not able to understand Class componets

Answer (score 0):

why you don't want to use the `disabled` attribute?
like: `<option disabled={theFuncReturnedTrueOrFalse} >value</option>`

so if you have to wait for data from API,
i think you can use the optional chain `?`:

```
let disabledItemsArr=["5","7"];

{data?.purpose?.map((items) => (                             
    <option disabled={disabledItemsArr.includes(items.value)}> 
         {items.value}</option>                         
))}
```

-_-

Comment: But the data is coming from backend , So How Can I add true or false for particular object... ANy suggestions

Comment: so u can add `?` symbol for your map
`{data?.purpose?.map((items) => (
                            //console.log(items.value);
                            <option disabled={!items.isEnable}>{items.value}</option>
                        ))}`

optional chain

Comment: If i try like this then all dropdown values are getting into disabled mode, I need only few options to be disabled not all